# SAPUI5 Scrollbar container issu

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, sapui5

I have a horizontal scroll bar in my mater page that disappears when I minimize and maximize the window.I have done a lot of search but could not find a css property that makes the scroll bar stay after minimizing and maximizing .
could anyone please give me some hints please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the content of your master page inside a

```
new sap.m.ScrollContainer({
horizontal : true,
vertical : false,
});
```

and set this container as Master content.

If this doesn't work, please show more code.